# Matplotlib semilog plot line of best fit

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below (blue dashed line) is what I get when I try to do linear regression on my data. It looks very off (but maybe it's correct?) Here is the image (does not allow me to embed):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KiprZDB.png]

and here is the code:

```
mm, cs, err = get_cols(data)
a = np.asarray(mm, dtype=float)
b = np.asarray(cs, dtype=float)
ax.errorbar(a, b, xerr=None, yerr=err, fmt='o', c='b', label='Detection Rate')
logB = np.log10(b)
m, y0 = np.polyfit(a, logB, 1)
ax.plot(a, np.exp(a*m+y0), '--')
```

Comment: you shouldn't mix `np.exp` (basis e = 2.72) and `np.log10` (basis 10)

Comment: oops. what should i use instead then? should i just raise it to the power of 10? it doesn't seem to fix the problem. 

nvm: i just changed it to log instead of log10

Answer (score 0):

The log scale of matplotlib uses the logarithm of base 10 by default. It therefore makes sense to use `np.log10(b)` to transform the data for fitting.

However, once fitting is done, the data needs to be backtransformed using the inverse of the transformation function.

In case of `y = log10(x)` the inverse is `x = 10**(y)`, while
in case of `y = log(x)` the inverse is `x = exp(y)`.

So you need to decide for one of the cases.